# problem adding elements dynamically with materializecss

Tags: javascript, frontend, materialize

I'm quite new using javascript, and I have a problem adding elements dynamically from a js function.

I'm using node.js + express + ejs + materializeCSS and I have a partial view with a card, if I include this file in the rendered ejs everything works fine, but if a add the same elements dynamically the label in text-inputs are overlapped.

When I add the card with the partial view using "include" it happens the same, but almost immediately the text-inputs refresh and the labels are ok. So my guess is that something happens after DOM is loaded.

For testing, I called the function that creates the card before the file is fully rendered and it worked ok too, it doesn't work if I call the same function after the DOM is fully loaded.

I checked the doc for text-inputs in MaterializeCSS site but there's no initialization for that.

this is how I include the first cards in the ejs (open_text.ejs) and the second one using the js function before DOM is fully load (both works fine)

```
<div id="content">
   <%- include('../partials/cards/create/open_text') %>  
   <script type="text/javascript">create_card('text');</script>
</div>
```

this is how I add the same card but using a button (it's the exactly same content than the ejs file used above)

```
function create_card(type){
    let text_card = "";
    text_card+=     '<div class="row">'
    text_card+=         '<div class="col s6 offset-s3"> <span class="flow-text"></span>'
    text_card+=             '<div class="card white-text darken-1">'
    text_card+=                 '<div class="card-content black-text">'
    text_card+=                     '<form class="container">'
    text_card+=                         '<div class="row">'
    text_card+=                             '<div class="input-field row s12" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">'
    text_card+=                                 '<i class="material-icons prefix">comment</i>'
    text_card+=                                 '<input placeholder="Please type the question Title" id="question_title" type="text" class="validate" required data-length="40">'
    text_card+=                                 '<label for="question_title">Question Title</label>'
    text_card+=                             '</div>'
    text_card+=                             '<div class="input-field row s12" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">'
    text_card+=                                 '<i class="small material-icons prefix">format_color_text</i>'
    text_card+=                                 '<input value="500 characters limit" id="text_area" type="text" disabled>'
    text_card+=                                 '<label for="text_area">Open Text Area</label>'
    text_card+=                             '</div>'
    text_card+=                             '<div class="switch" id="switch1">'
    text_card+=                                 '<label> Mandatory <input type="checkbox"> <span class="lever"></span></label>'
    text_card+=                                 '<a class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light red tooltipped" id="btn_delete_card" data-position = "bottom" data-delay = "50" data-tooltip = "delete card" style="margin-left: 20px;">'
    text_card+=                                 '<i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>'
    text_card+=                             '</div>'
    text_card+=                         '</div>'
    text_card+=                     '</form>'
    text_card+=                 '</div>'
    text_card+=             '</div>'
    text_card+=         '</div>'
    text_card+=     '</div>';

    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML +=  text_card;

}
```

[in this picture you can see the first two cards are ok, but the last one added from a button using the function, the labels overlaps the text below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fx5W.png)

Any help will be appreciated !

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

after adding "class=active" in labels worked ok